# Background database for AWS AppSync

Tags: aws-appsync

I would like to know what is the background database that AWS AppSync uses to store data on the cloud? I didn't find this info in documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

AppSync currently supports Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Elasticsearch, and AWS Lambda. With AppSync, you attach existing AWS resources to your API as "data sources" and then use AppSync resolvers to connect your GraphQL API to the underlying data source. For ease of use, AppSync also provides a feature that helps you deploy a DynamoDB table with the same shape as a type in your schema and will automatically register the data source and wire it up with resolvers on your behalf.

One of the great features of GraphQL is that it provides a single, unified protocol through which you can talk to any number of backend systems and AppSync embraces that philosophy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify what does mean by "..existing AWS resources to your API"?

Comment: Sure! AppSync is in many ways a serverless GraphQL gateway that comes with nice client tooling to enable offline-first and real-time sync workflows. An AppSync API uses GraphQL to expose itself to the network but AppSync does not actually store any of your information itself. To store data with AppSync you register your own Amazon DynamoDB tables, Amazon Elasticsearch domains, and AWS Lambda functions as "data sources" and then configure resolvers so that your clients can talk to those data sources with GraphQL through AppSync.